# Where can I find this bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

1. F. Black and M. Scholes. "The Pricing of Options and Corporate Liabilities." *Journal of Political Economy* 81 (May-June 1973), 637-59.
2. M. Brennan and E. Schwartz. "The Valuation of American Put Options." *Journal of Finance* 32 (May 1977), 449-62.

Comment: This isn't  enough information to determine what the style requires.  How are citations done  in the text? How are books formatted? Papers in collections? Theses? etc. How are multiple references by the same author formatted. There's a lot that goes into a bibliography style, unfortunately.  Is the a style for a particular journal?

Answer (score 1):

The style looks like ieeetr. Download IEEEtran from CRAN. The package homepage is here: http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/

Comment: its not ieeetr , although it has some similarity